# Android Google maps release

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am using android studio.I create new project and select new Google maps android activity.In `google_maps_api.xml`
there is a link to generate the api key.
Google maps works fine on my real device attached.BUT
After clicking "Build->Generate Signed Key" i generate apk and after installing apk the map doesn't works.
ADB Log

```
11-01 18:00:45.427  16721-16769/? D/REQUEST﹕ Error processing: 
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@42d27480 not retrying
    11-01 18:00:45.427  16721-16769/? D/REQUEST﹕ Retrying: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.j@42cf3e40
    11-01 18:00:45.427  16721-16769/? D/REQUEST﹕ Retrying: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.au@42e15028
    11-01 18:00:45.627  16721-16769/? D/REQUEST﹕ Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
    11-01 18:00:45.627  16721-16769/? D/REQUEST﹕ Open Connection
    11-01 18:00:45.887  16721-16769/? D/REQUEST﹕ DRD(10): 62|15|147
    11-01 18:00:45.897  16721-16769/? D/REQUEST﹕ Close
```

I searched a lot and found but nothing worked.

SUMMARY:Google maps works with device attached but doest not works after generating APK.

Comment: Are you changing the SHA-1 Key on Google API Console?

Comment: Changing? I am using only one key for testing and release

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you what I have done in Eclipse. You need to make a signing keystone and obtain the SHA1 fingerprint from it. In eclipse right click on project->Export android application ->Create key store. With the keystore you can obtain the SHA1 fingerprint and **update the same in Google API console** where you have enable maps for your project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem this morning, You need a different key for the debug and the release version! This [Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#the_google_maps_api_key)  will allow you to get a release key, after you will need to add your key to your AndroidManifest.xml file ?

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
    YOUR-KEY-HERE
</string>
```